# Mapp XML Doc to C# Class

Tags: c#, xml

I've researched that an XML document can be mapped to a C# class for easy access. I tried to read up on this but it seems pretty complicated for my C# knowledge...How would I mapp the document below to a C# class?..I want to access all of the ns1: example

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://addressplus.corelogic.com/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:CLAddressV2Response xmlns="http://addressplus.corelogic.com/">
         <ns1:CLAddressV2Result>
            <ns1:ErrorCode />
            <ns1:MatchCode>S80</ns1:MatchCode>
            <ns1:LocCode>APCL</ns1:LocCode>
            <ns1:Postalized>YES</ns1:Postalized>
            <ns1:IsForeign>NO</ns1:IsForeign>
            <ns1:Number>2435</ns1:Number>
            <ns1:NumberTo />
            <ns1:Fraction />
            <ns1:Predir />
            <ns1:Street>LINDA VISTA</ns1:Street>
            <ns1:Suffix>ST</ns1:Suffix>
            <ns1:Postdir />
            <ns1:Unitnumber />
            <ns1:PsdNumberPrefix />
            <ns1:PsdNumber>0000002435</ns1:PsdNumber>
            <ns1:PsdNumberFraction />
            <ns1:PsdNumberTo />
            <ns1:FullAddress>2435 LINDA VISTA ST</ns1:FullAddress>
            <ns1:City>CLARKSTON</ns1:City>
            <ns1:State>WA</ns1:State>
            <ns1:Country>UNITED STATES</ns1:Country>
            <ns1:ForeignCSZ />
            <ns1:ForeignLastLine />
            <ns1:ForeignLabel />
            <ns1:ZIPCode>99403</ns1:ZIPCode>
            <ns1:ZIP4>1431</ns1:ZIP4>
            <ns1:CRRT>C007</ns1:CRRT>
            <ns1:CRRTZone>D</ns1:CRRTZone>
            <ns1:DPBC>35</ns1:DPBC>
            <ns1:Latitude>46.3899590</ns1:Latitude>
            <ns1:Longitude>-117.0920820</ns1:Longitude>
            <ns1:RBDI />
            <ns1:CBSA>30300</ns1:CBSA>
            <ns1:MSA />
            <ns1:LOT>0278</ns1:LOT>
            <ns1:LOTOrder>A</ns1:LOTOrder>
            <ns1:CensusTract>960200</ns1:CensusTract>
            <ns1:CensusBlockFull>3008</ns1:CensusBlockFull>
            <ns1:CensusBlockGroup>3</ns1:CensusBlockGroup>
            <ns1:CensusBlock2>00</ns1:CensusBlock2>
            <ns1:CensusBlockSuffix>8</ns1:CensusBlockSuffix>
            <ns1:DPVCMRA>N</ns1:DPVCMRA>
            <ns1:DPVConfirm>Y</ns1:DPVConfirm>
            <ns1:DPVFootnote1>AA</ns1:DPVFootnote1>
            <ns1:DPVFootnote2>BB</ns1:DPVFootnote2>
            <ns1:DPVVacant>N</ns1:DPVVacant>
            <ns1:LACSLinkInd />
            <ns1:FIPS>53003</ns1:FIPS>
            <ns1:FIPSState>53</ns1:FIPSState>
            <ns1:FIPSCounty>003</ns1:FIPSCounty>
            <ns1:CountyName>ASOTIN COUNTY</ns1:CountyName>
            <ns1:ProcessCode>PCQD</ns1:ProcessCode>
            <ns1:Parcel>11200000600020000</ns1:Parcel>
            <ns1:ParcelSeq>1</ns1:ParcelSeq>
            <ns1:MapPageGrid />
         </ns1:CLAddressV2Result>
      </ns1:CLAddressV2Response>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Recommend not loading documents into custom classes, there's no real advantage there.  Reduce, Reuse, Recycle.  In this case use the XmlDocument object, then use SelectNodes with XPath to get what you need.  Be sure to add in the namespace too.

Answer (score 0):

The XML that you've posted looks like a SOAP response from a web service. Assuming that is the case and you are using a .Net project and added that web service as a [web reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5th1ba(v=vs.80).aspx), a proxy class CLAddressV2Response will be generated for you.

When making the RCP which returns this class this SOAP response will be automatically converted you.

Answer (score 0):

**Using [xsd.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) you can convert XML to (.cs)Class**

```
D:\temp>xsd test.xml
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'D:\temp\test.xsd'.

D:\temp>xsd test.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'D:\temp\test.cs'.
```